# Should I use different backgroud colors in my app?

Tags: color, themes, background

I want to design an app and my idea is to have 2 different background colors/themes:

1. standard theme for sides where users just need to navigate
2. theme for input sides where users need to make some input

The themes have different background colors, font colors and there is no top navigation on the second theme.

Is it a good idea? If not, please provide some usability rules.

Comment: What is your idea based on? What's the reasoning you have for having two themes?

Answer (score 3):

If your themes will be either displayed to one group of users in which one people may use theme 1 in some cases and theme 2 in other cases, It is better to use visually similar themes for both sides. You could use some other visual elements to emphasize different status.

Using two different colors in this case may cause confuse and reduce simplicity in your app interaction workflow. **As this Adobe blog advises**: [Users should never question the integrity of a product. The same colors, fonts, and icons should be present throughout the product](https://theblog.adobe.com/4-golden-rules-ui-design/).

But if there are different peoples whom work separately with your app's sides, In this case it's OK to use different colors. How over don't forget to keep colors near. Usually a little darker color is suitable for admin state.

[This Apple guideline](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/) can help you too.

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand this correctly you plan to use  different colour themes to separate modes.

One objective is not confuse the user with the colour changes and don't make him loose focus.

Consequently, a subtle colour theme is required. Small changes that indicate exactly want you want but don't overdo it.

However there are others views to separate visually the different modes.

Also, here is a helpful ui design guide

https://medium.com/@erikdkennedy/color-in-ui-design-a-practical-framework-e18cacd97f9e